# Can parameter DESTINATION for INSTALL be empty?

Tags: cmake

In general, relative parameters of type `PATH`, like "lib" or "source/include" are resolved in CMake to an absolute path using current value of variables, like for instance: `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` in case of command `INSTALL`. This, however, does not work if I would like to use empty relative path (or not set it at all), so that the resulting absolute path was equal to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` - CMake generator would complain about non existing `DESTINATION`, although there is no reason why it couldn't be resolved.

I know two workarounds to this issue, but the both have their flaws which prevent me from achieving my goal:

1. Use `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` as the `DESTINATION` value. This correctly resolved the path, but in case of `INSTALL(EXPORT)`, paths in generated `Target.cmake` are absolute, which makes the package not relocatable.
2. Use `.` as the `DESTINATION`. This at least generates relative paths inside `Target.cmake`, but the paths are incorrect. `.` is apparently considered as a regular folder, and in the process of `Target.cmake` generation, when `_IMPORT_PREFIX` is determined, CMake strips one folder component too much:

   ```
   # Compute the installation prefix relative to this file.
   get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
   get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
   ```

Is there any other workaround? Do you think that lack of empty relative paths could be considered a bug?

Comment: What's your CMake version?

Comment: 3.8, but has this changed over cmake versions?

Comment: I have same problem and I just found your question after reviewing what is happening during export file generation in cmake source code. So I think there is no option to just generate export where _IMPORT_PREFIX is simply set to "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}". I dont know why, for me it also seems to be pretty common use case where you have a package with library binaries, include files and cmake export file to import it, and it dont have to be hard pinned somewhere in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found some hacky solution for that. This will force cmake to generate the export file where `_IMPORT_PREFIX` is set to current location of the exported cmake.
Right before the install and export sequence modify CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX like this:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "\${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}/..")
```

The `\` sign before `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}` prevents from evaluating variable reference `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}` at this point, it is just passed as a string.
After that in exported cmake you will get:

```
set(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}/..")
```

You need to add `/..` at the end because `set` function will set the `_IMPORT_PREFIX` as a whole path to exported cmake, together with the cmake file name (eg. `C:/Works/project/ext/library/Library.cmake`) so the `/..` will drop `/Library.cmake`. Perfect result would be to just force cmake to use `get_filename_component` in exported file, like:

```
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
```

But as I mentioned in a comment it is probably impossible regarding cmake implementation.

I don't know if modifying `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` has no any negative side effects. On UNIX platform you can try to use `DESTDIR` instead of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` as an argument for `make`, but I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 0):

`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` works for me. Without the necessity of adding the `/..`.

@[Marek Kijo] - thanks for your solution with:
`set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "\${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}/..")`

Answer (score 0):

> Can parameter DESTINATION for INSTALL be empty?

CMake 3.14 added support for default install locations based on the type of file or target being installed.

From the docs:

> For regular executables, static libraries and shared libraries, the DESTINATION argument is not required. For these target types, when DESTINATION is omitted, a default destination will be taken from the appropriate variable from GNUInstallDirs, or set to a built-in default value if that variable is not defined. The same is true for file sets, and the public and private headers associated with the installed targets through the PUBLIC_HEADER and PRIVATE_HEADER target properties. A destination must always be provided for module libraries, Apple bundles and frameworks. A destination can be omitted for interface and object libraries, but they are handled differently (see the discussion of this topic toward the end of this section).

IE the following is now valid:

```
add_executable(my_app)
install(TARGETS my_app)
```